# Password protected PDF creation using Ghostscript

Tags: php, ghostscript

I need to provide password to PDF file using Ghostscript in PHP.
I have a PDF file called `sample.pdf`. I need to put protection to it and call it `output.pdf`.
I searched a lot and got the following lines of codes. But it doesn't helped me. Is there any error in my code? Any suggestion will be appreciated..

```
 exec("gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pswrite -sOutputFile=File.ps sample.pdf");
 exec("gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sOwnerPassword=pwd1 -sUserPassword=pwd2 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=output.pdf File.ps");
```

Answer (score 2):

Running the command lines you have given works here for me. Here are some questions:

1) Have you tried this from the command line instead of 'exec' from PHP ?

2) Why are you first running to pswrite, then back to pdfwrite ? This will give very poor quality

3) What version of Ghostscript are you using ?

4) In what way does this not work ? How are you testing the existence of password security ?

Comment: 1)i just try this in my php code.I tried to run this in the command [prompt also,but it says "gs is not recognised as an internal or external cmd.",[im trying this in windows platform].

Comment: 2)Right You are,This was my second attempt.I Tried the correct method but then also no effect.

Comment: 4)The pdf also not creating for me.I dont know the reason.Im dealing with ghostscript for the 1st time.

Comment: The Ghostscript executable is called gswin32 (or gswin32c for the command line version) on 32-bit windows and gwin64 on 64-bit windows. I would use the current release, 9.07, for testing. You seem to be saying that the output file is not being created. Can you post the stderr and stdout output from Ghostscript, as well as the actual command you are using.

Comment: when i run this code in my cmd prompt , it says that gswin32 is not recognised as an internal or external cmd...my gs version is 9.04.

Comment: Well until you can run Ghostscript from the command prompt I can't really see how it will work from anywhere else either. Most likely you don't have the installed Ghostscript in your PATH environment variable. Check to see where it is installed, it is usually installed in C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.04 in there should be a 'bin' sub-directory containing the executables. Add that directory to your PATH environment variable.